# Django - passing JSON data to the front-end along with HTML not working

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-rest-framework

This is my view:

```
import json

class UserPageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = User.objects.get(pk=17).username
        return TemplateResponse(request, template="user.html", context={'userya':json.dumps(obj)})
```

And then in my template, I have this JS: `console.log(userya);` but when I try to log it, it gives an error saying:

```
ReferenceError: userya is not defined
```

How do I pass JSON to the front-end using Django so that JS can access it?

Note: I am also using DjangoRestFramework and wasn't able to figure out how to do this with DRF either. If anyone knows a way to do it using DRF, that would be great.

Also mote that in my `user.html` template, I link to a `user.js` file and in that file is where I am doing `console.log(userya)`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the Django template variable syntax in your template.

```
console.log({{ userya }});
```

Comment: Does this work on your end? I'm getting an error on my console saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` when I try this. Note that in my `user.html` template, I link to a `user.js` file and in that file is where I am doing `console.log({{ userya }})`.

Comment: Well, that would have been useful information. The point is you need to output the Django variable *somewhere* so that the JS can pick it up: JS itself has no knowledge of your Django context. If you did this in user.html it would work fine.

Comment: Sorry. But okay, so basically, the only way for me to use the `userya` variable in JS is if I have the JS directly within the `.html` page?

Comment: Or write it to a global JS variable there, which your external JS can then access.

Comment: Hm, how exactly do I write it to a global JS variable? From my Django view?

Comment: by doing `window.userya = {{ userya }}`?